# Need temperature readings from a live CD/USB

Tags: linux, physical-environment, live-cd

I have a laptop that is sometimes restarting and I want to check if it is overheating.  It is an Intel dual core laptop and it doesn't have the temperature sensor readings as an option in the BIOS setup menu.  I want a program/script on a live CD or bootable USB to read whatever temperatures I can for the motherboard/CPU/HDDs/etc.

Comment: Got the laptop model number? Brand? These sorts of things are often subjective, and will change depending on the model numbers provided. It's even possible (but unlikely) that it doesn't have any temperature sensors.

Comment: I work with different computers, so I need a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you want to use [lmsensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/).  There is a good [list of supported hardware](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/ProjectInformation), so I hope that your device will be covered. [Here is a good guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-get-sensors-information/).

Comment: lmsensors is part of SystemRescueCD, its just a little confusing to use.  The guide linked above is good.

Answer (score 1):

Try any [Fedora 11 Live CD](http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-all).  (Fedora Desktop Live Media.)  Boot into GNOME.  Right click on any GNOME panel and select "Add to Panel..." and scroll down to "Hardware Sensors Monitor."  Select and click "Add."  Viola, you should now see temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [mbmon](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/mbmon/) and [hddtemp](http://www.guzu.net/linux/hddtemp.php)

Answer (score 0):

From a WinPE disk, you can use CPU-Z/GPU-Z/HDTune to see proc/gfx/hdd temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

Just go like this:

```
/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/TZ0[0-9]
cat temperature
```

It'll tell the temperature according to your current locale, even, I think.

Comment: SystemRescueCD doesn't have anything listed in /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/ on the machine I have in front of me.  What distro are you using?